# Issue in listagg

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have to concatenate 2 columns and put the value. but the problem is even if both the values are null it is still giving (:) as per below syntax. is there anyway we can remove column in the output if both values are null.

```
listagg(AP.ISSUE_ID||':'||ISS.ISSUE_DESCRIPTION ,'; ') within group(order by AP.ISSUE_ID||':'||ISS.ISSUE_DESCRIPTION) DESCRIPTION,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ignore a column in `listagg()`, set the value to `NULL`.  In this case, Oracle accepts `NULL` values for string concatenation.  So, let's do a test after the concatenation:

```
listagg(nullif(AP.ISSUE_ID ||| ':' || ISS.ISSUE_DESCRIPTION, ':'),'; ')
    within group (order by AP.ISSUE_ID || ':'|| ISS.ISSUE_DESCRIPTION) as DESCRIPTION,
```

Comment: Many many  thanks Gordon....you have always helped me whenever I had any issues...thank you so much again Gordan.

Answer (score 0):

```
AP.ISSUE_ID || nvl2(AP.ISSUE_ID || ISS.ISSUE_DESCRIPTION, ':' || ISS.ISSUE_DESCRIPTION, null)
```

Comment: Thanks..Semicolon was ignored in above commnd.